# Generating missing yearly data, based on a more detailed temporal data set

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatio-temporal-data, missing-data

I have several very large raster data sets of land use classifications (ie. forest, wetland, argicultural, etc).

The most comprehensive data spans 2009-2015. I have reclassified this data to match the categorizations used in an older data set. My problem is that the older data only exists once per decade (1990, 2000, and 2010). As you can see, I have 2 different data sources for 2010, which might come in handy.

I want to know if there is a way to generate data for how the land may have changes in those 10 year gaps. Is there a way for ArcMap to populate the missing data from 1991-1999 and 2001-2009, where it first looks at which rasters have changed in those 10 years. Then in each generated data set (1 new set for each missing year) each raster that changed in those 10 years has a 1 in 10 chance of having changed from A to B in any given year. So as an example: by the time it generates the 1999 data, 90% of the rasters should have changed - with the year 2000 representing 100% of the changes.

I have a follow up question, which is much more advanced. So my main focus would be on answering the first part.

Because I have the complete 2009-2015 data, maybe there would even be a way to extrapolate how changes occur based on that existing data? Such as a spatial relationship, like if one raster changed from forest to agriculture, it is now more likely that the adjacent rasters also changed that same year.